# Creating instance of javascript sub type yields unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, inheritance

The title is a little vague, but I honestly can not define it any better than that without understanding the solution to this problem.

### The situation

I'm trying to wrap my head around prototypes and inheritance in javascript.
The use case is a single base type 'A'. And a single sub type 'B'.
Here is an example of the simplest code that demonstrates the issue.
A working version can be seen [here](http://jteeuwen.nl/code/js/inherit.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function A () {
        this.node = document.createElement('div');
        this.node.innerHTML = 'A';
    }

    A.prototype.show = function () {
        document.body.appendChild(this.node);
    }

    function B () {
        this.node.innerHTML = 'B';
    }

    B.prototype = new A();
    B.prototype.constructor = B;

    function make_a () {
        (new A()).show();
    }

    function make_b () {
        (new B()).show();
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="make_a()">Make A</button>
  <button onclick="make_b()">Make B</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

### The problem

- Clicking the first button does what I expect it to do: It creates a new instance of 'A' on every click and adds it to the DOM.
- Doing the same with the second button however, adds only 1 instance of 'B' to the DOM and leaves it at that. Regardless of how many times one clicks.
- If you click 'A' after this, a new 'A' is once again created as expected.
- Clicking the second button once more, simply moves the existing 'B' node to the last place in the node list.

Why is `make_b()` not behaving the same way as `make_a()`?

### Some notes:

Browsers being tested in are Chromium 20+ and Firefox 13+.

Comment: Use `Object.create` instead of `new` and rejoice.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't really explain why the above doesn't work.

Comment: The issue is that `node` is a property of `B.prototype` rather than a property of the individual instances of `B`. This means every instance of `B` is sharing the same `node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `A` constructor from within your `B` constructor:

```
function B () {
    A.call(this);
    this.node.innerHTML = 'B';
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QUnDK/

Answer (score 1):

For explanation:

when modifying

```
A.prototype.show = function () {
    document.body.appendChild(this.node);
    document.body.appendChild(this.node);
}
```

one can see that multiple calls of appendChild with the same node parameter do not cause multiple appendend childs.

When modifying

```
function B () {
    this.node.innerHTML = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "B":"C";
}
```

one can see that function B overrides the last inserted child (by A). (B() itself does not create a div).

Function A() is called on page load through the instruction B.prototype = new A(); and whenever button A is pressed.
So there is always a latest created div child before button B may be activated. This latest created div is appended
to the document whenever show() is called, i.e. in reaction to a button click.

Function B() does not create a new div-node so B() uses the latest child node created/appended by A() to insert "B" in.